# Display posts from category in page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop

I am trying to use a shortcode to display a loop of posts from a category. I have the shortcode working but it is only displaying the actually category names within the custom post type and not the actual posts. Below are the basics:

Custom Post type is "business"
Taxonomy is "business_taxonomy"
Category made within the CMS is "dfa"

The shortcode code is

```
add_shortcode( 'list-posts', 'rmcc_post_listing_parameters_shortcode' );
function rmcc_post_listing_parameters_shortcode( $atts ) {
    ob_start();

    // define attributes and their defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array (
        'type' => '',
        'order' => 'date',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'posts' => -1,
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts ) );

    // define query parameters based on attributes
    $options = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'order' => $order,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'posts_per_page' => $posts,
        'category_name' => $category,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $options );
    // run the loop based on the query
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <h5><?php the_title() ?></h5>
    <?php
        $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
        return $myvariable;
    }
}
```

so in the page I should put `[list-posts type="business" category="dfa"]` but nothing shows. If I use just `[list-posts type="business"]` it just lists the category names in the custom post type not the actual posts titles.

Comment: This should work, can you check and confirm if the category `dfa` has posts in it.

Comment: is that the full code? I don't see the `while(); ... endwhile;` of the actual loop.

Comment: It comes from here http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-shortcode-to-list-posts-with-multiple-parameters--wp-32199

Comment: @BradDalton Ya, I was looking at that code and finally got it to work. The code in that tutorial is broken unless you download it, dont use the posted code to edit.

Comment: @Packy Please add your solution as separate answer.